# Change color of binscatter plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, scatter

I would like to change the color of the binscatter I have done but I am unsure what is the syntax. I saw I can use colormap(gca,'parula') but I would like to change it to one specific self defined color. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own colormap by creating a matrix of RGB-triplets. This matrix should be an m-by-3 matrix with values between 0 and 1. Every row represents one color in the map.

```
map = [0.1 0.5 0.1
       0.3 0.5 0.3
       0.5 0.5 0.5
       0.7 0.5 0.7]
```

Then use the map in the same way as you suggested yourself.

```
colormap(gca,map)
```

If you don't want to manually type in all the colors that you want you can generate them by doing someting like this:

```
n = 40; % Number of colors
R = linspace(0,1,n); % Red color changes
G = linspace(0,0,n); % Green color changes
B = linspace(0,0,n); % Blue color changes

map = [R',G',B']; % Compose colormap
colormap(gca, map) % Set colormap
```

This will give a colormap with 40 colors that goes from black to red. You can experiment with the start and end values in the `linspace` to get other combinations of colors. Basically each column in `map` will describe how you want each color to change.

There are many more predefined colormaps other than `parula`. You can find them here if you scroll down a bit. [Colormaps](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)